TypeScriptでglobalThisに追加したプロパティが認識されない
TypeScriptでglobalThisに追加したプロパティが認識されない
TypeScriptを使用してElectronアプリを開発しています。globalThisにカスタムのlog関数を追加し、その型をglobal.d.tsに定義しています。しかし、TypeScriptのコンパイル時に以下のエラーが発生し、解決方法が分からず困っています。
エラーメッセージ
error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.

試しているコード
以下がglobal.d.tsファイルの内容です。
// src/utils/global.d.ts
declare global {
  interface GlobalThis {
    log: (message: string) => void;
  }
}

export {};

また、メインプロセスで次のようにlogを使用しています。
// main.ts
globalThis.log = logWithCallerInfo;
globalThis.log('main.ts');  // グローバルログを使用

global.d.tsの型定義を用いて、globalThis.logをTypeScriptに認識させようとしていますが、エラーが消えません。
ただし､エラーが出ている状態でも､Electronをビルドすればlog関数は期待通り動作します｡
試した解決策

global.d.tsの位置がsrc/utilsにあることを確認し、tsconfig.jsonに以下の設定を追加しました。

{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {"*": ["node_modules/*"]},
    "typeRoots": ["./src/utils", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*",]
}


global.d.tsをコメントアウトしても動作には問題ないですが、エラーが消えないままです。

使用環境

TypeScript: 4.7.4
Node.js: 16.14.0
Electron: 32.0.1
Visual Studio Code

質問
global.d.tsで定義したglobalThisのlogプロパティがTypeScriptに認識されるようにするには、どうすれば良いでしょうか？他に試すべき設定や方法があれば教えていただけると助かります。
